# Can the EXCEPT operator exclude data where a column contains data from an array

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, linq-to-sql

Assume there is a string of text values comma-separated, like an array:

```
var excludelist ="apples,oranges,grapes,pears";
```

The excludelist values may come from a query to a table in a database.

Assume a query wherein we want to return all rows EXCEPT those rows where the field named Fruit contains any items from the excludelist.

```
var qry = from s in context.Groceries.Where(s => s.Fruit(here is where we need to exclude the items??) join u in context.Users on s.Owner equals u.User_ID
```

Can someone provide a sample Link to SQL answer?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Except`?

```
var qry = from s in context.Groceries.Except(excludelist)...
```

Link to SQL has `CONTAINS` (and!CONTAINS)

```
where !excludelist.Contains(i)
        select i;
```

Comment: The exclude list ony exists in Groceries field/column named Fruit, so I don't think Groceries.Except will work.

Comment: I also have tried .Where(s => excludelist.Any(qz => s.Fruit.ToLower().Contains(qz))) and it compiled OK, but the result populates a jgrid and an unexplained javascript error resulted.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

I have a database table with the names of the fruits I wish to exclude and I created a List (IList apparently won't work).

```
List<string> excludedfruit = context.ExcludedFruit.Select(x => x.ExcludedFruitName).ToList();
```

Then I used the following Linq to SQL query (partially shown)

```
        var qry = from s in context.Groceries
                .Where(s => !excludedfruit.Contains(s.Fruit))
```